# Why my APP load a view before main view?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[image]
I do not know what the first view is.The second view is my APP's main layout.Please help me.Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check our Android manifests.xml file

`<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>`

This set of code is responsible for the lunching first activity

You need to put this inside your activity tag like this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/test"
           >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
This is my  activity tag. I think it is right.

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure your main Activity class is calling in the correct Layout. Are you using Android Studio with Genymotion?

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
```

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);
  
 }     I am using eclipse with Genymotion.